# How to connect webscraping data to a database?

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

I want to create webscraper which stores the values of stocks in a database. Now the thing is stocks update every second so how can i make a database that updates every second? I'll be using python for webscraping. How can i upload,update and fetch the data to a database and also which database should i use?

Comment: I also had to make a similar project but since it takes a lot of time to collect the data and the site updates second it was hard to collect it. I found out that the site stopes updating after 9pm so colleting data was easier at that time. Try checking it site at night times or check there Session Timings.

Comment: the teacher asked me to get my data updated with real time thats the issue